# Excel reformatted numbers to times

Tags: microsoft-excel, cell-format

I have a spreadsheet stored on a company Sharepoint site. Only one person in my team will use it at any time, when they're finished it saves and is available to another user. Periodically when someone opens it a column of numbers (integers) will have reformatted and be displayed as time 00:00:00, why is this happening and how I can prevent it? (No one is manually making the change)

Answer (score 1):

Excel will do this when people enter numbers the wrong way. If you type in any number followed by a colon (**:**) followed by a number, Excel will treat this as a time and change the cell accordingly.

In order to prevent this, format the cells and set it to a value:

1. Optionally select more than one cell or column that you want to edit.
2. Right-click the cell/selection.
3. Choose "Format Cells".
4. Choose anything but the top item (top is sort of an auto setting).
5. Press OK to make the changes.

And that's basically it.